# `IO::Socket::INET: connect: Connection refused` when connecting to JDBC database

Tags: database, perl, jdbc

I am new to Perl and there is a script for database connection

```
sub db_connect {
    my ($database, $user, $password) = @_;

    my $driver = "JDBC";
    my $port = 14000;

    my $dsn = "dbi:JDBC:hostname=localhost:14000; url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:1111/$database;jdbc_character_set=ASCII";

    my $db_handler = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password ) or die $DBI::errstr;

    print "DB connected\n";
    return $db_handler;
}
```

and following is the error:-

```
process name:- com.vizdom.dbd.jdbc.ServerDBI connect('hostname=localhost:14000;url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:1111/EciToolDB;jdbc_character_set=ASCII','SA',...) failed: Failed to open socket to server: IO::Socket::INET: connect: Connection refused at ../lib/utils.pl line 66
Failed to open socket to server: IO::Socket::INET: connect: Connection refused at ../lib/utils.pl line 66.
```

Comment: Could you post your full code and tell us about line 66?

Comment: Just to be clear, it's not a *db_handler*, it's a *db_handle*. There is a huge difference

Comment: my $db_handler = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password ) or die $DBI::errstr;  this is line no. 66

Answer (score -1):

According to the [DBD::JDBC docs](http://search.cpan.org/~vizdom/DBD-JDBC-0.70/JDBC.pod), you need to have the java server process running in order to make the above connection.  It looks like that process isn't responding on the port you are trying to connect to.

`java -Djdbc.drivers=foo.bar.Driver -Ddbd.port=14000 com.vizdom.dbd.jdbc.Server`